# Native-Image binary not supporting a server effeciently

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

In my java application i have created a JettyServer.
In GraalVM i have implemented it and did a load test with it , i didn't find any issues.
I then converted the java application to a static **native-image binary** .
And if I do load test with this, I get many `Connection refused` errors
For example : in 10k requests atleast 3k gave me connection refused errors, where as in graalvm-java it worked fine.
The following args i have given while building the image
`native-image -J-Xmx359M -J-Xms256M -J-Xmn256M --static -H:+MultiThreaded`

Comment: **Can anyone help me how to overcome this ..??**

Comment: looks like they are waiting for commands at https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/5578, if you put a reproducer it will help to investigate the issue.